# Exchange Powershell - how to create alias as first initial last name?

Tags: exchange, powershell

I have a script that I downloaded off of Technet.

Problem is that it creates the alias as:

```
-Alias ($_.FirstName +  ($_.LastName).ToUpper())
```

where `$_.Firstname` is the -FirstName field and `$_.LastName` is the -LastName field.

I'd like to create it as first initial last name instead.

example:

Joe Smith

should become `jsmith` as the alias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.

```
-Alias (($_.FirstName.Substring(0,1)) + ($_.LastName))
```

Hope that helps someone else.

Comment: @uSlackr - yeah I know...but there is a waiting period.  Can't do it until tomorrow.